# Is there any conflict to use camelCase when naming web/desktop software projects?

Tags: javascript, java, php, asp.net-mvc

Can someone tell me if there is any problem when using camelCase to name a web or desktop software project in asp.net mvc, java, javascript or php?

Also does this generate problems when using the underscore [ _ ] in the middle of the name of the project example: projectName or project_name? What is recommended to name a project in these technologies?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, project names are conventionally in MixedCase, with first letters of words capitalized and no spaces in between.

I do not know much about the other languages you have mentioned, I suggest you do a simple Google search to find out.

Answer (score 1):

I though that you talk about "Naming Convention".

You can make your own rule to give a name to each of your project even if it's web or desktop project.

It could be xx-yy-zz or XxYyZz or anything else according to you.

Hope this reference helps
[Naming convention for new projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130075/naming-convention-for-new-projects)

Additional:
Except for file name or variable name or etc in programming language, each of programming language have their own rule for it. For a simple example you can find it when learning about Basic Programming or Object Oriented Concept.